# conversion issue while putting transformer to read string having date values

Tags: date, type-conversion, format, transformation, datastage

I have the two fields

`November 14  2019 10:35:24 AM` and `November 14  2019` as string from file

I want to convert in datstage to these fields as

`11/14/2019  10:35:24AM` and `20191114` respectively

Please note: after month there is one space between November and 14 and two spaces between 14 and 2019

and in output 11/14/2019 and time there is two spaces

Answer (score 0):

As the input is a string and it seems you want again a string as a result string manipulation functions in a Transformer stage are always an option.

Alternatively you could also try to use the [String_to_Timestamp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Type_Conversion_Functions.html) and STRING_TO_DATE function on the same page

You will find valid format options [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_date_Formats.html)